# Convert array of objects to array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, mapping

Given is an json object like this:

```
var items = [{
    title: 'sample 1',
    image: 'http://www.lorempixel.com/700/600/'
}, {
    title: 'sample 2',
    image: 'http://www.lorempixel.com/900/1200/'
}, {
    title: 'sample 3',
    image: 'http://www.lorempixel.com/400/300/'
}, {
    title: 'sample 4',
    image: 'http://www.lorempixel.com/600/600/'
}, {
    title: 'sample 5',
    image: 'http://www.lorempixel.com/400/310/'
}, {
    title: 'sample 6',
    image: 'http://www.lorempixel.com/410/300/'
}, {
    title: 'sample 7',
    image: 'http://www.lorempixel.com/500/300/'
}, {
    title: 'sample 8',
    image: 'http://www.lorempixel.com/300/300/'
}, {
    title: 'sample 9',
    image: 'http://www.lorempixel.com/450/320/'
}, {
    title: 'sample 10',
    image: 'http://www.lorempixel.com/500/400/'
}];
```

I Want to get an array like this.

```
[['sample 1', 'http://www.lorempixel.com/700/600/'], ['sample 2', 'http://www.lorempixel.com/900/1200/'], ....]
```

I tried something like this:

```
const rows = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                const element = items[i];
                rows[i] = element.title;
                for (let j = i; j < items.image; j++) {
                    const el = response[j];
                    rows[j] = el.image;
                }
            }
```

I get an array containing only all images, i think because i override other values in the second loop. What should be the right way to get both values like described ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply pass `Object.values()` as callback to `.map()`:

```js
let data = [
  {title: 'sample 1', image: 'http://www.lorempixel.com/700/600/'},
  {title: 'sample 2', image: 'http://www.lorempixel.com/900/1200/'},
  {title: 'sample 3', image: 'http://www.lorempixel.com/400/300/'},
  {title: 'sample 4', image: 'http://www.lorempixel.com/600/600/'},
  {title: 'sample 5', image: 'http://www.lorempixel.com/400/310/'}
];

let result = data.map(Object.values);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a simple `.map` - extract the appropriate property values from the object, and return an array containing those two values:

```js
var items=[{title:'sample 1',image:'http://www.lorempixel.com/700/600/'},{title:'sample 2',image:'http://www.lorempixel.com/900/1200/'},{title:'sample 3',image:'http://www.lorempixel.com/400/300/'},{title:'sample 4',image:'http://www.lorempixel.com/600/600/'},{title:'sample 5',image:'http://www.lorempixel.com/400/310/'},{title:'sample 6',image:'http://www.lorempixel.com/410/300/'},{title:'sample 7',image:'http://www.lorempixel.com/500/300/'},{title:'sample 8',image:'http://www.lorempixel.com/300/300/'},{title:'sample 9',image:'http://www.lorempixel.com/450/320/'},{title:'sample 10',image:'http://www.lorempixel.com/500/400/'}];

console.log(
  items.map(({ title, image }) => [title, image])
);
```